# Curvature of a hyperboloid of one sheet

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

How can I prove that a one sheet hyperboloid has a negative curvature? Also, how can I show that this shape expands to infinity?

Comment: Compute $LN-M^2$ of second fundamental form coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent it (locally) as graph of a function, compute the Hessian, and show that its determinant is negative. The graph "expands to infinity" because for every pair $(x,y)$ outside the unit circle, you can find an appropriate $z$.